# Self-intersecting path of stacked regular tetrahedra

Tags: discrete-geometry, polyhedra

(This question occurred to me after reading 
[@IanAgol's reminisces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/357197/conways-lesser-known-results/357668#comment898138_357197)
of Conway's spiral tetrahedron billiard path.)

Let $T_i$ be a regular tetrahedron,
and $P$ a collection of regular tetrahedra
glued together face-to-face.
Say that $P$ constitutes a
"path of stacked regular tetrahedra"
iff two conditions hold:

1. The dual graph (node for each $T_i$, arc if $T_i$ shares
   a face with $T_j$) is a path.
2. No edge of the construction is incident to more than three tetrahedra.

The first condition intuitively insists on a snake-like object.
The second condition excludes too many tetrahedra circling about
one edge. (Without this, $5$ dihedral angles of $70.5^\circ$ 
fit into $360^\circ$, but $6$ do not.)

My question is:

> ***Q***.
>   What is the fewest number of tetrahedra in a path $P$ of stacked regular tetrahedra that self-intersects?

$P = \cup_i T_i$ self intersects if a pair of
distinct tetrahedra share a point strictly interior to both.
So such a self-intersecting snake might be called
a *tetrahedral ouroboros*.

This example<sup>1</sup>
establishes an upperbound of $31$ tetrahedra 
(adding one more would self-intersect),
but clearly this is not the minimum number of tetrahedra.
(This example was aiming toward closure, not self-intersection.)

---

[image]

          

<sup>Fig.6(detail): $QH_7$: $4L+2=30$.</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>
Elgersma, Michael, and Stan Wagon. "The quadrahelix: A nearly perfect loop of tetrahedra." 
[arXiv:1610.00280](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.00280) 
(2016).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Michael Elgersma, a coauthor on the paper I cited, provided an answer to my question:
an $11$-tetrahedra snake suffices to self-intersect. Here is his illustration of
the first $10$ tetrahedra:

---

[image]

---

He also sent me a convincing proof of optimality:

**Theorem**: The shortest tetrahedal snake that has self intersections, has length $11$.