# Generalization of Tucker circle, Conway circle and van Lamoen circle

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, plane-geometry

Theorem 9.1 in [this paper](http://geometry-math-journal.ro/pdf/Volume7-Issue2/5.pdf) as follows is a generalization of [Turker circle](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TuckerCircles.html). Turker circles is a generalization of many circles as: [Cosine Circle](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CosineCircle.html), [circum circle](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circumcircle.html), [First Lemoine Circle](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FirstLemoineCircle.html), [Gallatly Circle](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GallatlyCircle.html), [Kenmotu Circle](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KenmotuCircle.html), [Taylor Circle](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TaylorCircle.html), [Apollonius Circle](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ApolloniusCircle.html).

The [Conway circles](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConwayCircle.html) and [Floor van Lamoen circle](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/vanLamoenCircle.html) are also special case of Turker circle.

I also given some anothert nice special cases of Theorem 9.1, example Theorem 9.2, Theorem 9.3, Theorem 9.6, Theorem 9.7 of [that paper](http://geometry-math-journal.ro/pdf/Volume7-Issue2/5.pdf).

**Theorem 9.1.** Let $ABC$ be a triangle, let points $D$, $G$ be chosen on side $AB$, points $I$, $F$ be chosen on side $BC$, points $E$, $H$ be chosen on side $CA$, let $k$, $l$ are real number such that:

$\begin{cases} \angle EDA =kA+lB+(1-k-l)C\\ \angle FEC =(1-l)A+(k+l)B-kC\\ \angle GFB = (1-k-l)A+kB+lC\\ \angle HGA =-kA+(1-l)B+(k+l)C \\ \angle IHC=lA+(1-k-l)B+kC \end{cases}$

Then six points $D, E, F, G, H, I$ lie on a circle and $ \angle DIB = (k+l)A-kB+(1-l)C$

[image]

**Coverse of Theorem 9.1:** Let $ABC$ be a triangle, let points $D$, $G$ be chosen on side $AB$, points $I$, $F$ be chosen on side $BC$, points $E$, $H$ be chosen on side $CA$ and six points $D, E, F, G, H, I$ lie on a circle. Then exist two real numbers $k$, $l$ such that:

$\begin{cases} \angle EDA =kA+lB+(1-k-l)C\\ \angle FEC =(1-l)A+(k+l)B-kC\\ \angle GFB = (1-k-l)A+kB+lC\\ \angle HGA =-kA+(1-l)B+(k+l)C \\ \angle IHC=lA+(1-k-l)B+kC \\ \angle DIB = (k+l)A-kB+(1-l)C \end{cases}$

> > **My question:** Is the converse of Theorem 9.1 true?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnot%27s_theorem_(conics)