# Is there an inventory of closed billiard paths in a regular tetrahedron?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, billiards

[Conway found](https://mathoverflow.net/q/357197/6094) a closed billiard-ball trajectory in a regular tetrahedron:

[image]

<sup>Image: [Izidor Hafner](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ConwaysBilliardBallLoop/)</sup>

Since then Bedaride and Rao

> Bedaride, Nicolas, and Michael Rao. "Regular simplices and periodic billiard orbits." *Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.* **142**, no. 10 (2014): 3511-3519.
> [JSTOR link](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24507260).

proved this:

**Theorem**. In a regular simplex $\Delta^n \subset \mathbb{R}^n$
there exists at least two periodic orbits:

- One has period $n + 1$ and hits each face once.
- The other has period $2n$ and hits one face $n$ times and hits each other face once.

For $n=3$, Conway's path accounts for the first length-$4$ periodic path.
I haven't yet figured out explicit coordinates for their second length-$6$ path.
I'd be interested if anyone has drawn this $6$-path.
In any case, my question is:

***Q***. Is there a complete inventory of periodic billiard paths in
a regular tetrahedron?

Is it even known that there are only a finite number of
such paths?